# Pathologies involving non-generic filters

Tags: set-theory

This is a question regarding exercise (IV.2.46) in Kunen's Set Theory (2011); it reads:

"Assume that $M$ is a ctm for $ZFC$, and let $\mathbb{P}$ $=$ Fn$(\omega,2)$. Then there is a filter $G$ on $\mathbb{P}$ such that there is no transitive $N\supseteq M$ such that $G\in N$ and $N\models ZF-P$ and $o(N)=o(M)$."

I think I have a proof of this claim, but after reviewing it multiple times, it doesn't seem to use the conditions "$M\models ZFC$" nor "$N\supseteq M$". In other words, given a transitive countable $M$, I was able to construct an explicit filter $G$ (depending on $M$) on $\mathbb{P}$ such that $o(M)\neq o(N)$ whenever $N\ni G$, $N$ is transitive, and $N\models ZF-P$.

I'm not looking for a solution to this exercise, as I'd like to solve it myself, but I'm only wondering if the conditions "$M\models ZFC$" or "$N\supseteq M$" are necessary. (In the case of necessity a counter-example would be nice).

Also, if any of the notation in the exercise is unclear or not standard then please leave a comment and I will explain the notation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should tell us more about your proposed solution. As it is, neither of the two hypotheses you mention is very important, I think. In fact, depending on how you solve this, it will probably be the case that $M\in N$ whenever $G\in N$. I expect the assumptions are there just to connect the problem more tightly to the usual forcing setup.

Comment: I followed Kunen's hint, which reads: "$G$ can code a well-order of $\omega$ of type larger than $o(M)$"

Comment: So I started with a countable transitive $M$ and considered the first ordinal not in $M$, which is $o(M)$ and is countable in this case, and I considered a well-order $\sqsubset$ of $\omega$ of order type $o(M)$. Then I defined a filter $G$ on $Fn(\omega,2)$ which consisting of all functions in $Fn(\omega,2)$ coding partial segments of $\sqsubset$ (I'll omit the specific details of the coding).

Comment: Then assuming $G\in N$ for $N$ a transitive model of $ZF-P$, I get $\bigcup G\in N$ and is a function which encodes all of $\sqsubset$. Then by basic absoluteness results of transitive models of $ZF-P$, I get that there is some unique ordinal $\alpha\in N$ such that $(\omega;\sqsubset)\cong(\alpha;<)$. And then by uniqueness, the ordinal with this property must be $o(M)$, and therefore $o(M)\in ON\cap N=o(N)$, which means that $o(M)\neq o(N)$.

Comment: Your solution is fine. You can push it a bit further and have $G$ code the entirety of $M$ and get $M\in N$ that way.